# Importing xlsx data to R when numbers have a comma as decimal separator

Tags: r, excel, readxl

#### How can I import data from a `.xlsx` file into R so that numbers are represented as numbers, when their original decimal separator is comma not a dot?

The only package I know of, when dealing with excel is `readxl` from `tidyverse`.

I'm looking for a solution that won't need opening and editing excel files in any other software (and can deal with hundreds of columns to import) - if that would be possible I'd export all excels to `.csv` and import them using tools I know of, that can take the `dec=` argument.

So far my best working solution is to import numbers as characters and then transform it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

var1<- c("2,1", "3,2", "4,5")
var2<- c("1,2", "3,33", "5,55")
var3<- c("3,44", "2,2", "8,88")
df<- data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3))

df %>%
      mutate_at(vars(contains("var")),
                str_replace,
                pattern = ",",
                replacement = "\\.") %>%
      mutate_at(vars(contains("var")), funs(as.numeric))
```

Comment: You can try with "read.xlsx" function from "xlsx" package. Don't forget use 'stringsAsFactors=F' and then try to convert with `as.numeric(gsub(',','.' column_name))`

Comment: I'm a little surprised actually that it doesn't just work. (I assume you've tried it? What happens when you do?) I started exploring it on my Mac and it looks like Excel uses the overall system locale to decide how to present the numbers (comma or dot). I haven't been bold enough to try switching mine to see what happens, though.

Comment: looks like there is no `dec=` argument in `readxl`: `Error in read_excel("df.xlsx", skip = 5, dec = ",") : unused argument (dec = ",")`

Comment: Do you need the argument at all, though?

Comment: If no argument is used all values are imported as characters

Comment: Bummer. What does it look like in Excel? That is, are they really numbers there or are they character strings?

Comment: In my excel (polish locale) they are numbers .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162629/discussion-between-blazej-and-aaron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect strongly that there is some other reason these columns are being read as character, most likely that they are the dreaded "Number Stored as Text".

For ordinary numbers (stored as numbers), after switching to comma as decimal separator either for an individual file or in the overall system settings, `readxl::read_excel` reads in a numeric properly. (This is on my Windows system.) Even when adding a character to one of the cells in that column or setting `col_types="text"`, I get the number read in using a period as decimal, not as comma, giving more evidence that `readxl` is using the internally stored data type.

The only way I have gotten R to read in a comma as a decimal is when the data is stored in Excel as text instead of as numeric. (You can enter this by prefacing the number with a single quote, like `'1,7`.) I then get a little green triangle in the corner of the cell, which gives the popup warning "Number Stored as Text". In my exploration, I was surprised to discover that Excel will do calculations on numbers stored as text, so that's not a valid way of checking for this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741991/how-to-convert-text-to-numbers for a start on dealing with numbers stored as text in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to replace the "," with a "." and recast the column as numeric. Example:

```
> x <- c('1,00','2,00','3,00')
> df <- data.frame(x)
> df
     x
1 1,00
2 2,00
3 3,00
> df$x <- gsub(',','.',df$x)
> df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)
> df
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
> class(df$x)
[1] "numeric"
>
```

Just using base R and gsub.

Comment: looks easy with one or two columns - gets a bit complicated with hundreds of colums to `gsub` one by one

Comment: Hmm good point, and I could see the shortcomings of using a loop as you added to your question. Have you tried the `ReadColumns` function from the `xlsx` package? It may work on localized data since it uses the internally stored Excel data type.

Comment: From quick perusal of the readxl code, it seems to use the internally stored Excel data type too.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem while dealing with an Excel spreadsheet I had received from a colleague. After I had tried to import the file using `readxl` (which failed), I converted the file into a `csv` file hoping to solve the problem using `read_delim` and fiddling with the locale and decimal sign options. But the problem was still there, no matter which options I used.

Here is the solution that worked for me: I found out that the characters that were used in the cells containing the missing values (`.` in my case) were causing trouble. I went back to the Excel file, replaced `.` in all cells with missing values with blanks while just keeping the default option for the decimals (`,`). After that, all columns were imported correctly as numeric using `readxl`.

If you should face this problem with your decimals set to `.` make sure to tick the box saying "Match entire cell contents" in Excel before replacing all instances of the missing values `.`