# Excel numbers formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, format, numbers

I have the following dataset:

```
Scope   month   Category    Receipts_Category   Turnover Category_Gross Quantity_Category
es      2020-11 Favorina,     Deluxe, Dor        11349    192950,62          79506,21
es      2020-11 Favorina,     Deluxe, Dor        4851     111597,19          43268,30
es      2020-12 Favorina      Deluxe, Dor        383      6546,97            1834
es      2020-12 Favorina      Deluxe, Dor        11       458,03             237
```

As you can see, from the "Quantity_Category" column, there are 2 types of numbers, the floats and the ones that are exact. The problem is that I have to enter inside the cell and click enter for every cell if I want to get the same number format.
For example, if I enter inside the cell for **1834** and I click enter, the output will be **1834,00**.

I need this ,00 format for the exact numbers as if not the graphs I'm creating will not be ok, as some data is not taking into account.

Does anyone know a better way than go one by one in order to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Comment: Hello @BigBen, all numbers are placed in the left side of the cell, any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741991/how-to-convert-text-to-numbers/2742065.